# Why "set" can't assign value to custom SettingKey I can "show" in sbt shell?

Tags: scala, sbt

The following is a sbt `0.13.1` project with a custom setting and a value for it:

```
% pwd
/Users/tisue/myproj
% ls
build.sbt
% cat build.sbt
val foo = settingKey[String]("This is a custom setting")

foo := "bar"
% sbt
[info] Set current project to myproj (in build file:/Users/tisue/myproj/)
> show foo
[info] bar
```

So far so good. But now:

```
> set foo := "qux"
<set>:1: error: not found: value foo
foo := "qux"
^
[error] Type error in expression
```

Shouldn't this work?

I partially understand what's going wrong here; `set` evaluates a Scala expression, and that expression is apparently being compiled in a context where `val foo` is not in scope.

But I would expect that the magic that makes sure `foo` is in scope when `foo := ...` is compiled from the `.sbt` file, would also be in effect when the same thing is compiled in the shell.

Comment: It's similar to the error `eval` gives. With `eval foo = "hello"` sbt errors with `<eval>:1: error: not found: value foo` while `eval name = 4` ends with `<eval>:1: error: reassignment to val`. It appears custom settings are not *sourced* in a session.

Comment: https://github.com/sbt/sbt/pull/1456

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of release 0.13.6 (2014-09-12) this is no longer a limitation ([#1059](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1059)/[#1456](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/pull/1456))

---

*Original Answer - for any projects using sbt 0.13.0 - 0.13.5*

As it turns out [0.13.0 changes](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.0/docs/Community/ChangeSummary_0.13.0.html#sbt-format-enhancements) clearly state that this is an expected behavior:

> All definitions are compiled before settings, but it will probably be best practice to put definitions together. Currently, the visibility of definitions is restricted to the .sbt file it is defined in. They are not visible in `consoleProject` or the `set` command at this time, either. Use Scala files in project/ for visibility in all .sbt files.

With this, you should be able to share the setting after it's defined in `project/Build.scala` as follows:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object HelloBuild extends Build {
  lazy val foo = settingKey[String]("This is a custom setting")

  foo := "Build.scala"
}
```

**build.sbt**

```
scalaVersion := "2.10.4-RC1"

foo := "build.sbt"
```

Then, in sbt shell:

```
[sbt-0-13-1]> foo
[info] build.sbt
[sbt-0-13-1]> set foo := "shell"
[info] Defining *:foo
[info] The new value will be used by no settings or tasks.
[info] Reapplying settings...
[info] Set current project to sbt-0-13-1 (in build file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/)
[sbt-0-13-1]> foo
[info] shell
```

Comment: Thanks Eugene. The “currently” and “at this time” in the passage you quote seem to indicate that Mark hopes to lift this limitation in a future version.